# Google Sheets doesn't load all Images

Tags: google-sheets

I often use Google Sheets for illustrating things, but quite often friends and myself can't see all images.
This can rarely be fixed by refreshing the page, but very often some pictures are missing.

It's like that for all kinds of functions. (=image, =vlookup, =[cell reference])

My question is: Is there a way to see all images?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

- Close all the open programs in order to release all the computer and Internet resources
- Use a faster Internet connection
- Use a faster computer
- Reduce the complexity of your spreadsheet like replacing the formulas that aren't required to be calculated every time that the spreadsheet opens by their values, reduce the number of sheets, columns, rows
- Reduce the number of images

Comment: As I said, the problem applies to all visitors of the sheet. Therefore the first three suggestions wont help.

Your fourth and fifth suggestion would obviously help, but I can't do that, because it's already as small as possible.

Still thanks for your effort :/